# How to create agent that starts other intents?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Using `API.AI` agent code, I can create Conversational Agents for use with Google Home wireless speaker device.
That is basically ask a question, get a verbal reply.

Is there anyway to code up a response that is not just a reply, but actually a Direct Action?
For example:
Intent: Switch to radio station 2
Response: Play 88.3 New York Radio
and it should work as if I had asked to play that radio station.

This may be something what Google calls "Direct Actions".
But I understand that is not available yet.
Is that correct, that there is no way to do what I need above - essentially have one intent start another build-in Google Action intent - in this case, to have it play a radio stations?
I was wondering if there is some webhook/fulfillment hook code that can do this today.

Comment: You are referring to Events. Please check this link, https://dialogflow.com/docs/events

Answer (score 1):

You currently can not proxy from one Action to another. Direct Actions are still to be released.

You would have to get your webhook to handle the implementation based on parameters.